# how to get a string using match function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I ma trying to get the string starting from * and ending on * using the match function.I getting a array of strings not a one string. 
My code is

```
Str="==Quotes==* We thought that he was going to be -- I shouldn't say this at Christmastime -- but the next messiah.** On [[Barack Obama]]"

regE=/\* \w*/gi
newArr=str.match(regE)
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Match gives you all the matches, what did you expect?

Comment: `regE = /\*(.*?)\*/; newArr=str.match(regE); console.log(newArr[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was slightly off. To match between two asterisks, you're looking for `/\*([^*]*)\*/gi`:

```js
str = "==Quotes==* We thought that he was going to be -- I shouldn't say this at Christmastime -- but the next messiah.** On [[Barack Obama]]";
regE = /\*([^*]*)\*/gi;
newArr = str.match(regE);
console.log(newArr[0]);
```

Note that **[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** returns an **array** of matches. In order to get the first match, you can simply access the first index with `[0]` as above.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use either:

1. Non-greedy match (Try to match as smaller string as it can) :

```js
str = "==Quotes==* We thought that he was going to be -- I shouldn't say this at Christmastime -- but the next messiah.** On [[Barack Obama]]";
    regE = /\*.*?\*/gi;
    newArr = str.match(regE);
    console.log(newArr[0]);
```

2. Greedy match (Try to match as bigger string as it can) :

```js
str = "==Quotes==* We thought that he was going to be -- I shouldn't say this at Christmastime -- but the next messiah.** On [[Barack Obama]]";
    regE = /\*.*\*/gi;
    newArr = str.match(regE);
    console.log(newArr[0]);
```